# How to change sort icon in detailslist

Tags: fluentui-react

I am using detailslist, is there a quick property to change sort icon?

[image]

I find below [styles](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/react/idetailscolumnstyles?view=office-ui-fabric-react-latest#properties) but do not know how to set it

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's not possible because `sort icon` is implemented directly inside [DetailsColumn.base.tsx](https://github.com/microsoft/fluentui/blob/master/packages/react/src/components/DetailsList/DetailsColumn.base.tsx#L168):

```js
{column.isSorted && (
 <IconComponent
   className={classNames.sortIcon}
   iconName={column.isSortedDescending ? 'SortDown' : 'SortUp'}
 />
)}
```

But if you really need that functionality you can recompose `DetailsList Component`. Hint:

```js
<DetailsList
  onRenderDetailsHeader={(headerProps, defaultRender) => {
     return headerProps && defaultRender ? (
       {defaultRender({
         ...headerProps,
         onRenderColumnHeaderTooltip: props => {
           return <TooltipHost {...props} children={/* Implementation here! */} />
         }
       })}
     ) : null;
  }}
/>
```

Keep the same [children functionality](https://github.com/microsoft/fluentui/blob/master/packages/react/src/components/DetailsList/DetailsColumn.base.tsx#L141) and rewrite icon render.

[Codepen example](https://codepen.io/savkelita/pen/WNXLLMm?editors=0010) for hint.

Comment: oh. seems that you're right.  this is not possible by default.  what's a pity

Answer (score 0):

You are able to achieve what you want by doing some css trickery. In my use-case I only had to change the color. In the example below I added a background-image for setting your own icon.

```
<DetailsList onRenderDetailsHeader={(headerProps, defaultRender) => {
                                    return defaultRender({
                                        ...headerProps,
                                        styles: {
                                            root: {
                                                selectors: {
                                                    '.ms-DetailsHeader-cell': {
                                                        backgroundColor: '#0f238c',
                                                        color: 'white' 
                                                    },
                                                    '.ms-Icon': {
                                                        color: '#0f238c',
                                                        backgroundColor: '#0f238c',
                                                        backgroundImage: decendingFilter ? 'url([PATHTOIMG1])' : 'url([PATHTOIMG2])',
                                                        backgroundRepeat: 'no-repeat',
                                                        backgroundSize: 'contain',
                                                    },
                                                },
                                            }
                                        }
                                    });
                                }}
                            />
```